# Getting HTML of GridPanel in Ext JS

Tags: extjs, javascript

I have a GridPanel which is completely ready and working. It is currently rendered to the DOM by calling the `render(id)` method of `Ext.grid.GridPanel`.

This results in the GridPanel beeing rendered right before the html element with the given id.

For programming in my API i now need the rendered HTML of the table in my JavaScript to pass it to another function which can just act on HTML code and i can't change it for compatibility reasons. So the render function doesn't return anything and i don't know how to get the html or at least a reference to the DOM-node of the rendered HTML in JavaScript.

any suggestions?

Comment: Just my 2ct but it sounds horribly wrong what you are trying to do ... pass the generated html code of a complete grid through your API? What are you doing that for?

Comment: See, i don't really need the HTML code itsself. A better way would of couse be to have a handle to the DOM Element of the Grid but i can't seem to get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just not possible to render the table before the element exists **AND IS ADDED TO THE DOM** in  which the grid should be rendered. That's really unflexible i think. But i am forced to use it by the project so i will have to change the API to **generate some entrypoint - DIVs** for the EXT grid before rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the HTML of the DOM node of the body of the grid by doing:

```
gridObject.body.dom.innerHTML
```

but it is not a table... it is markup styled to look like a table...

The best way to get grid data in HTML would be to add a method to the grid that renders its data into a template.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.XTemplate

Comment: Thanks but i think that only works after the table is rendered? This is where my problem lies, i can't render the table because there is no existing DOM element where i could render it to.

Comment: "Thanks but i think that only works after the table is rendered?" -- Can you clarify your question?  Did you mean to say grid instead of table?

Answer (score 1):

Create a dom element, say d.
Then do: 
Ext.fly(d).replaceWith(yourGrid.getEl())

This should replace your created dom element's contents with grid's contents.  This also retains all the state, since ext component is still there.

Comment: I'll have a look at this soon

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can actually a "String" of the HTML and pass it on to a function. But you should be able to get reference to the document element, simply by getElementById since you will know the element id (pass it into the config of the GridPanel). You'll simply get reference to the top-level  element.

Have you seen the kind of HTML generated by ExtJS? They are not that nice to work directly with, it's simpler if you work with the GridPanel objects.

Comment: Thanks so far. The problem i have ist, that i cannot rely on any other DOM Element on the page because the GridPanel could possibly be the only one. So i cannot parse any id to render() anymore. I don'nt want to manually manipulate the html but i need to pass the html through my API functions. There is a function called "placeWidget" which takes any DOM Element and puts it into a layout automaticly. I don't think i can get it by "getElementById" before it's attached to the document?